# How to generate all the combinations with repetition and another conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

I want to generate all the combinations with repetition for k variables with values from a set of n elements.

There are some ways, I like this formula, which I found on this forum (it is for n = 2 and k = 3, which is not a problem).

```
 With[{n = 2, k = 3},
  Join @@ Table[IntegerPartitions[s, {k}, Range[n]], {s, k, n k}]]
```

My question is, How can I add these conditions:

First: every value of n must be used at least once,
Second: every value of n must be used at most 10 times

Is there a way, how to improve the code above or should I try another method?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question, would `Select[Tuples[RandomInteger[n, {k, 3}]], Length[Tally[#]] == n + 1 &]` solve for the first criteria?

Comment: ```GroupTheory`Tools`Multisets[Range[n],k]```

Answer (score 1):

We want to choose k balls from n different types of balls.

As all n types must appear, there are only k-n balls to choose. Therefore, we need to choose k-n balls from n types, taking care not to use more than 10 times the same type. These may be created by:

```
inds = Table[{ind[i], ind[i - 1], n}, {i, k - n}] /. 
  ind[0] -> 1; vars = Cases[inds, {x : ind[_], __} -> x, 2];
check := If[Max[Length /@ Split[vars]] <= 10, vars, {}];
tmp = Flatten[Table[check, Evaluate[Sequence @@ inds]], 
   k - n - 1] /. {} -> Sequence[];
```

Finally, all combinations with repetitions and the given conditions are given by:

```
Sort[#] &@  Join[Range@n, #] & /@ tmp
```

For convenience we pack all this into a function:

```
getCom[k_, n_, maxn_] := Module[{inds, vars, check, tmp}, 
  inds = Table[{ind[i], ind[i - 1], n}, {i, k - n}] /. ind[0] -> 1; 
  vars = Cases[inds, {x : ind[_], __} -> x, 2];
  check := If[Max[Length /@ Split[vars]] <= maxn - 1, vars, {}];
  tmp = Flatten[Table[check, Evaluate[Sequence @@ inds]], 
     k - n - 1] /. {} -> Sequence[]; 
  Sort[#] &@  Join[Range@n, #] & /@ tmp 
  ]
```

where k is the number of balls to choose, n is the number of different types and nmax is the maximum number a type can appear.

Here is an example:

```
getCom[7, 4, 3]
```

[image]

Note that the output will be numbers. If your "balls" are different objects, e.g. "a","b".., you may replace in the result numbers by objects by:

```
result /. {1->"a",2->"b",...}
```

Comment: Can we try a specific example? I have 5 letters - a,b,c,d,e and 20 places. I have to use each letter at least once and at most 10 times. So the result can look like a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,c,d,e and so on. What about this?

Comment: Looking at your example, I realized, that I made an error in using `Tuples`. Unfortunately the code became now much more complicated, so that I packed it into a function. I changed my answer accordingly. Have fun.